# How to make a query request in SQL for preselecting rows before the main select

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, select, group-by

I have two tables T1 and T2:

T1:

```
|  ID  | Data |
---------------
|   1  | abcd |
|   2  | efgh |
|   3  | ijkl |
|   4  | mnop |
|   5  | qwef |
```

T2:

```
| Date |T1_ID | Info |
---------------------
| 8/1  |   1  | qrst |
| 8/2  |   1  | uvwx |
| 8/3  |   1  | yzab |
| 8/2  |   2  | cdef |
| 8/3  |   2  | ghij |
| 8/7  |   3  | klmn |
| 8/8  |   3  | opqr |
| 8/9  |   3  | stuv |
| 8/4  |   5  | wxyz |
| 8/5  |   5  | abcd |
```

T1 has a unique ID and some information. T2 has no unique ID, but a link to the ID of T1. Every entry of T2 belongs to one row in T1, but the are also rows in T1, which are not referenced by any row in T2.

What I did so far:

To get all data in one new table I made a select:

```
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Data, T2.Date, T2.Info FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.ID = T2.T1_ID WHERE T2.Date >= #8/2/2019#;
```

This gives me a new table:

```
|  ID  | Data | Date | Info |
-----------------------------
|   1  | abcd | 8/2  | uvwx |
|   1  | abcd | 8/3  | yzab |
|   2  | efgh | 8/2  | cdef |
|   2  | efgh | 8/3  | ghij |
|   3  | ijkl | 8/7  | klmn |
|   3  | ijkl | 8/8  | opqr |
|   3  | ijkl | 8/9  | stuv |
|   4  | mnop |      |      |
|   5  | qwef | 8/4  | wxyz |
|   5  | qwef | 8/5  | abcd |
```

But what I want to do, is making a select which only returns me the last date entry of each ID:

```
|  ID  | Data | Date | Info |
-----------------------------
|   1  | abcd | 8/3  | yzab |
|   2  | efgh | 8/3  | ghij |
|   3  | ijkl | 8/9  | stuv |
|   4  | mnop |      |      |
|   5  | qwef | 8/5  | abcd |
```

I tried some queries with MAX and GROUP BY, but I don't know how to "preselect" the maximum date of a certain T1_ID. Any ideas?

It's a small DB in MS Access.

Comment: Try with CROSS APPLY instead of join like cross apply (select top 1 * from T2 ORDER BY DATE DESC)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` and `group by` to get the latest date

```
select t1.id, t1.data, max(t2.date)
from t1 left join
     t2 
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id
group by t1.id, t1.data;
```

Then join again:

```
select t1.id, t1.data, t2.*
from t1 left join
     (select t2.t1_id, max(t2.date) as max_date 
      from t2 
      group by t2.t1_id
    ) as tt2 left join
    t2
    on t2.id = tt2.t1_id and t2.date = tt2.max_date;
```

Or, use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.id, t1.data, t2.*
from t1 left join
     t2 
     on t1.id = t2.t1_id
where t2.date = (select max(tt2.date)
                 from t2 tt2
                 where tt2.t1_id = t2.t1_id
                );
```

Comment: I created a second table (SELECT) inside the FROM segment. The JOIN was a little tricky, but it worked. I wasn't aware of the fact, that it's possible to create a sub table this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to preselect the rows and then left join the table T1 to the results of the preselection:

```
select t1.*, t2.[Date], t2.info
from t1 left join (
  select t.* from t2 as t
  where not exists (
    select 1 from t2
    where t1_id = t.t1_id and [Date] > t.[Date]
  )
) as t2 on t2.t1_id = t1.id
```